# Licencing a software while working in an enterprise

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation, software, license

I work for one of the 4 big consulting companies.

I developed a software on my free time. It gained lot of attention, I was asked to register it as company asset. I guess there are plans to use/sell it in the engagements with clients.

If I leave the company, I still want to be able to use it and if the company sells it, I wanted to be able to get some credit.

What is the best way to license it?

Thanks

Comment: Who will be copyright owner of the software? If it's the company rather than you, they decide the license, not you.

Comment: Can i be the copyright owner of the software?

Comment: What does your contract say about stuff done in your free time, and what does the agreement with your employer to register it as a company asset say?

Comment: It definitely depends a bit on your work contract - and where you live, thus which legislation applies and how closely related to your daily business is the software you developed. In principle you are the copyright holder, but you might be required to concede an exclusive license to your employer - for free. Best advice is: consult a lawyer, if your employer wants to exploit the stuff you did in your free time (and look for a new job)

Comment: I need to check my contract. But once it is a company asset I believe they hold several rights. Like i mentioned. It is one of biggest consulting company, if not the biggest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question of the poster's contract and agreement, not about open source software.

Comment: Big4 is chanceless.